# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while running Mockito from SBT

Tags: sbt, mockito

Looks like SBT classloading messes with Mockito.

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbtassembly.Plugin._
import AssemblyKeys._

object Build extends Build {
  lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
    .settings(
      name := "so-mockito",
      compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala,
      libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"
    )
    .settings(buildSettings: _*)
    .settings(assemblySettings: _*)
    .settings(mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.JavaMain"))
}
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.10.2")
```

**src/main/java/com/example/Consumer.java**

```
package com.example;

class Consumer {
    interface Input {
        String get();
    }

    private final Input input;

    static Consumer create(Input input) {
        return new Consumer(input);
    }

    private Consumer(Input input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

**src/main/java/com/example/JavaMain.java**

```
package com.example;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static com.example.Consumer.*;

public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Input input = mock(Input.class);
        System.out.println(String.format("[JavaMain] Created mock: '%s'", input));
    }
}
```

`sbt run` yields the following exception:

```
[info] Running com.example.JavaMain 
[error] (run-main-0) org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
[error] Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.example.Consumer$Input
[error] Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
[error] If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface com.example.Consumer$Input
Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
    at com.example.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
    at com.example.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
    at com.example.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.example.Consumer$Input$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$5997e3ec cannot access its superinterface com.example.Consumer$Input
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:110)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
    at com.example.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

However, running with `java` or `scala` works as expected:

```
> sbt assembly && java -jar target/scala-2.10/so-mockito-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JavaMain] Created mock: 'Mock for Input, hashCode: 1317029026'

> sbt assembly && scala -cp target/scala-2.10/so-mockito-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 'com.example.JavaMain'
[JavaMain] Created mock: 'Mock for Input, hashCode: 1035091326'
```

Can anyone confirm (SBT 0.13.1)?

Comment: Can you try to run SBT with Java 7? It sometimes helps.

Comment: i am running with Java 7

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when the access modifier for the inner `com.example.Consumer.Input` interface becomes `public` as follows (note the `public` keyword for the interface):

```
package com.example;

class Consumer {
    public interface Input {
        String get();
    }

    private final Input input;

    static Consumer create(Input input) {
        return new Consumer(input);
    }

    private Consumer(Input input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
}
```

A sample `sbt run` with `about` before to know the versions, plugins and such.

```
$ sbt about run
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/mockito/project
[info] Set current project to so-mockito (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/mockito/)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/mockito/}root 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, np.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin, sbtassembly.Plugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
[info] Running com.example.JavaMain
[JavaMain] Created mock: 'Mock for Input, hashCode: 256995217'
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 29, 2014 10:00:13 PM
```

BTW, in this particular build configuration using `build.sbt` might be a better choice as it'd become clearer.

**build.sbt**

```
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "so-mockito"

compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala

libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5"

sbtassembly.Plugin.buildSettings

sbtassembly.Plugin.assemblySettings

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.example.JavaMain")
```

Comment: while playing around with this simple example i did notice that changing the visibility of Input from package private to public will indeed "make it work" with SBT. however, this is beside the point. i'd like to stay away from designing a system around a tool (seems backwards). i'd say this is definitely a bug in SBT. good point about using `build.sbt` instead of `Build.scala`

Comment: Now, when I think about it (rather than focusing on solving the issue), it really could be an issue in SBT. Would you mind reporting it in [SBT issues](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues?state=open)?

Comment: In sbt, the default classloader is the one for the sbt launcher, but you are "run" in a sub classloader.  Does mockito require any funny classloader workarounds?  This would be the same as using mockito in any container, like OSGi or a Servlet container.

Comment: Yeah, it looks to me like mockito is automagically creating subclasses but doesn't appear to be either using the right classloader *OR* some kind of JVM security permission is preventing it.   I'm not really aware of the nitty gritty details of mockito.  If you can help isolate the issue, we can try to issue a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was beaten by a similar error when mocking flyway from scala code `mock[org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]` the test ran nicely through Intellij but through sbt test it raised: 

`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.flywaydb.core.Flyway`

for other googlers my solution was simply upgrading mockito core:

```
-        "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.7.22",
+        "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.15.0",

```